# Campo como parâmetro em Update genérico - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Atualmente possuo uma procedure que lê um XML, e faz um update nos campos da tabela **pessoa_fisica** com base nos valores enviados pelo XML, como CPF, RG, Nome, etc.

Hoje leio os valores do XML e insiro na variável da tabela.

```
pessoa_fisica_w         pessoa_fisica%rowtype;
```

Feito isso, faço o seguinte update.

```
update  pessoa_fisica
set row = pessoa_fisica_w
where   cd_pessoa_fisica = pessoa_fisica_w.cd_pessoa_fisica;
```

Hoje isso funciona.

O que preciso agora é receber o campo chave para fazer o update do XML. Atualmente está fixo **cd_pessoa_fisica = pessoa_fisica_w.cd_pessoa_fisica** e precisaria e preciso executar um update dinâmico.

Seria essa query:

```
Exec_sql_Dinamico('grava_log_01',
                  'update   pessoa_fisica ' ||
                  'set  row =' ||  pessoa_fisica_w ||
                  'where    ' || c01_w.ds_campo_acao || '= pessoa_fisica_w.'||c01_w.ds_campo_acao||';');
```

c01_w é o cursor com os valores obtidos do XML.

O meu problema é, como uma query dinâmica leria o **pessoa_fisica_w**, 
Hoje esbarro no problema **PLS-00306: número incorreto de tipos de argumentos na chamada para '||'** por causa da concatenação, e também  ocorreria problema na hora acessar o **pessoa_fisica_w.'||c01_w.ds_campo_acao**.

Haveria alguma forma de criar isso genericamente, ou teria que fazer manualmente todos os campos utilizando case/if e sempre passando fixo os campos do where update,  junto com o valores?

Comment: Os campos são char ?

Comment: Os tipos dos campos variam entrem varchar2 e number somente.

Comment: Os campos varchar2 e char precisam vir entre parenteses no comando UPDATE. Concate aspas para isto , creio que sintaxe é algo como ''''||campo||''''

Comment: O problema é que pessoa_fisica_w é um rowType, não é um varchar2, ocorre tipo inválido.

Comment: Row foi uma tentativa de setar todasxas colunas da tabela ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, pois, as colunas estão em contantes mudanças, por isso utilizei para setar todas as colunas. Também utilizei pelo fato de ser mais fácil manipular os valores quando transferidos do cursor do xml para a row.

Comment: Teria de montar um sql lendo a tabela de metadados dba_tab_columns

Comment: Certo, um problema resolveria, mas o problema de pegar dinamicamente o valor de um campo de dentro de um rowtype, será que haveria como, algo como pessoa_fisica_w.field('campo')?

Comment: Sim seria isto.Quando estiver em um PC tento montar uma resposta.

Comment: Fico no aguardo, pois, tive que deixar este problema de lado e verificar outros, já que não consegui achar uma solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia básisa em um bloco anônimo segue abaixo

```
DECLARE
  VS_SAI    VARCHAR2(4000);
  VS_TABELA VARCHAR2(30) := 'PESSOA_FISICA';--nome da tabela do banco
  WS_RNOME  VARCHAR2(30) := 'PESSOA_FISICA_W';--nome do array
BEGIN
  VS_SAI := 'UPDATE ' || VS_TABELA;
  VS_SAI := VS_SAI || ' SET ';
  --lê a matadados para montar as colunas 
  FOR R IN (SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = VS_TABELA)
  LOOP
    VS_SAI := VS_SAI || R.COLUMN_NAME || '=' || WS_RNOME ||'.'||R.COLUMN_NAME ||', ';
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VS_SAI);--APENAS PARA EXIBICAO 
END;
```

Comment: Certo, entendi esta questão, porém, sobre como visualizar uma informação dinâmicamente dentro do rowtype, não haveria como, isso? Pois, fazer o select com o campo dinâmico isso resolve, com o "VS_SAI" fazendo o enviado por você, porém dentro do  WS_RNOME ||'.'||R.COLUMN_NAME não haverá o valor que está dentro do meu rowtype.

Comment: a ideia e montar o sql o update que vai "pegar" o conteúdo.